# How do you register a domain without a TLD?

Tags: domain, domain-registration, tld

[image: a domain without a tld]
So I found this website that is visitable and does *not* have a TLD? Anyone got any idea how to do this?

Comment: `to.` [used to](http://www.domainnamenews.com/cctlds/worlds-shortest-url-shortener/6741) have an `A` record too

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It does have a TLD - in this case the TLD is `ac`.

This is actually a special case. Usually a TLD does not have an A record associated with it:

```
$ host -t A ac.
ac has address 193.223.78.210
$ host -t A com.
com has no A record
```

To get this behaviour, you would have to register your own TLD.

Answer (score 7):

New gTLDs can be registered like the recent `.xxx` for a small fee (US$185,000):

http://www.icann.org/en/topics/new-gtlds/strategy-faq.htm

Answer (score 6):

It's likely you're using a dns 'default search domain' configured most likely via DHCP or a local hosts file setting.

Comment: That, or something set in the hosts file.